# Appengine application as OpenId provider. Is it possible?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, openid, provider

I have an application hosted on Google AppEngine. This app requires users authentication. I know that users can be authenticaded through OpenId, Google Accounts and so on. However, some user don't have any of these accounts. Thus, i have to suggest that they create an OpenId or a Google Account before they can be able to access my application. 
I was wondering if it's possible to host an OpenId provider inside AppEngine, this way, instead of suggesting user to go away, create an OpenId and later get back, i could simply display a simple form. In this form, that user could create they new account and, at same time, create an OpenId, since the application would also be an OpenId Provider. 
I'm not sure if i could host and OpenId provider inside appengine . Would I?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/ contains a sample OpenID provider application. It uses Google accounts to authenticate, but it shouldn't be too difficult to use it to create your own accounts.

Of course, it's a bit bizarre that you want to create accounts on your service for the users but then use openID to authenticate them from that service to itself; why not just have a non-OpenID login in addition to OpenID if you want to manage some users' accounts yourself?

Comment: I just want to provide an alternative for those user who don't have an OpenId yet. If they don't have one, they could create their accounts on my service and later also use it on other services on the web. This way, they wouldn't need to leave the application , go create an OpenId account elsewhere.